# Many to many relationship CRUD in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have modeled a many-to-many relationship with Room based on the docs and this [medium article](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/handling-many-to-many-relationship-in-android-addb60a3a3). Using this @Relation I can retrieve RecipeWithIngredients or IngredientWithRecipe Objects from the database. For this to work I need to insert a recipe to the recipe table, an ingredient to the ingredient table then a reference with both of their ids to the reference table first. I don't think there is another way of doing insertion other than using @Transaction on the Dao and just doing it all on one method, however for deletion and updating shouldn't I be able to do those using the Relation as well? The documentation on Room looks a bit lacking to me and so I've come to you

[image]

```
//Get for recipeWithIngredients object. (This works)
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE recipeID = :ID")
suspend fun getRecipeWithIngredients(ID:Long): RecipeWithIngredients

//Insert recipeWithIngredients object. (I don't see why this wouldn't work)
//IDs are autoGenerated so I can't get them until they are inserted

@Transaction 
suspend fun insertRecipeWithIngredients(recipeWithIngredients: RecipeWithIngredients){
    val recipeID = insertRecipe(recipeWithIngredients.recipe)

    for(ingredient in recipeWithIngredients.ingredients){
        val ingredientID = insertIngredient(ingredient)
        insertRecipeIngredientRef(recipeID, ingredientID )

    }
}

//I could try doing this like the insert but should't there be a way to do it like the get?
@Transaction
@Query("SOME SQL HERE")
suspend fun deleteRecipeWithIngredients(recipeWithIngredients: RecipeWithIngredients)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think there is another way of doing insertion other than using @Transaction on the Dao and just doing it all on one method

Your idea implemented by `insertRecipeWithIngredients` is interesting and I guess it should work, but I wouldn't say it's a common way to do that. Many-to-many relation in general - is when you have two separate entities that have a value even without relationship between them (`User` & `UserGroup` or for example). Even in your use-case it can be that one user at first adds recipe with its short text description and needed steps then another user binds ingredients to it, so `insertRecipe` and `insertRecipeIngredients` should be done separately.
In this schema you should implement three separate `insert` methods - first for `Recipe`, second for `Ingridient` and third - for `RecipeIngridientRef`. But you of course in your specific case you can do like you've described above.

> for deletion and updating shouldn't I be able to do those using the Relation as well

Out-of-the box Room doesn't support that. It's only for queries.

If for **deletion** you want to delete rows from `RecipeIngridientRef` that are referenced to specific Recipe, than it would be enough to use `Foreign Key` standard mechanism - Cascade deleting. With that you need only to write `delete` for Recipe entity and the rest Room&Sqlite will do for you.

As for **update** it's really lack of recommendations in documentation. One of the choices - is first to delete all rows in `RecipeIngridientRef` with specific Recipe and then to use the same method insert for `RecipeIngridientRef` (both operations in transaction).

Comment: I just finished another in depth online search for enlightenment and found out everything you just said, the fact that you said it just confirms everything I've read. Thank you for sharing the knowledge.